# Optimizing loop by using floating point value as loop counter

Tags: loops, floating-point, numeric

I need to execute a loop

```
while (X) do Y
```

for a N times, which is a large number. While Y, the loop body, is rather quick, the test X takes up about 70% of the runtime.

I can calculate the number of loop iterations N beforehand so instead of using X as the condition, a simple For-Loop would be possible.

```
for (i=1 to N) do Y
```

However, N might exceed the maximum value an integer can store on the machine, so this is not an option. As an alternative, I proposed to use a floating point variable F instead. As N is large, it is likely that F cannot be exactly equal to N. Thus, I calculate F to be the largest floating point number smaller than N. This allows me to run

```
for (i=1 to F) do Y
while (X) do Y
```

Most of the iterations will not need to test X everytime, only the last N-F do.

The question is: How would I implement a for-Loop from 1 to F? Simply increasing a counter or decreasing F by 1 in each step would not work, as the numerical error would grow too large. My current solution is:

```
for (while F > MAXINT)
    for (i=1 to MAXINT)
        do Y
    F -= MAXINT
while (X) do Y
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by numerical error? Floating point counting is exact within its precision.
Here are the maximum values representable by integers exactly using the following data types:

```
uint32max     = 4294967295
uint64max     = 18446744073709551615
float32intmax = 16777216
float64intmax = 9007199254740992
```

Every integer from 0 to the max is exactly representable without numerical error.

As you can see, the largest count is available with uint64. Next comes float64, then uint32 and finally float32.

What happens when you increment uint32=4294967295 ? 0.

What happens when you increment float32=16777216 ? 16777216.

Which is the better behavior?

Have you thought about using a 2-dimensional loop? If N ism the maximum count for a 1-dimensional loop, then N x N is the maximum for a 2-dimensional loop, etc. so that if you maximum count is less than MAXUINT x MAXUINT, then decompose you number N such that:

```
N == M * MAXUINT + R;
```

where

```
M = N / MAXUINT;
R = N - M * MAXUINT;
```

then

```
for (i = M; i--;) for (j = MAXUINT; j--;) DoStuff();
for (i = R; i--;) DoStuff();
```

If MAXUINT*MAXUINT is not a large enough count for you, you can add 3-, 4-, ... -dimensional loops.

Comment: What you are describing is only a subset of floating point numbers which, as you showed yourself, contains less numbers than the integer data types. I am talking about the entire 32 bit floating point numbers. Regarding the 2-dimensional loop, there is no guarantee my number N is a square integer.

Comment: You can use nextafter() with floating-point to get access to all numbers, but this is the same as integers of the same length. I think that you are expecting more out of floating point numbers than there is.

Comment: @Pixels is correct. Every integer within the FP range is represented exactly and (starting from 0) the operation `f = f + 1.0` will be exact 1,677,7216 times for `real` and 9,007,199,254,740,992 times for double. But what kind of a system has `double` but no 64-bit int?

Comment: @RealityPixels I never said anything about me expecting something from floats. I stated my current solution (which uses floats) and asked if it possible to do better. The proposal you edited into your answer should work. I don't really like it since it does not scale arbitrarily but it is still better than my current approach.

Comment: @DigitalRoss I can't remember saying either that RealityPixels was incorrect regarding that statment nor that my system does not offer a 64-bit integer data type.

Comment: Think of the loop counter as a state variable. Since a 32 bit number has only 4,294,967,296 possible states, 4,294,967,295 is the maximum loop size that you can have, if you terminate when the state reaches 0. It doesn't matter whether it is a 32-bit float, a 32-bit integer, a 32-bit color..., what matters is the distinct number of values that it can attain.  You can use any state transition mechanism as well as decrement-by-1 to keep track of the state.